# UITabBarController moreNavigationController as a grouped TableView?

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

I am using a UITabBarController that has more than 5 items, so it shows the more tab.

Is it possible to make this moreNavigationController be a grouped TableView (uitableviewstylegrouped)?  Currently it defaults to a normal table view.

Comment: Love to know the answer as well.

Comment: Did you ever figure out if this was possible?

Comment: @derrichh: No, never figured it out.

Answer (score 3):

Try giving exactly 5, instead of giving more than 5 and let the 5th be the host of your grouped table view controller

Answer (score 3):

The following code snippet does precisely that. It uses the instance of UITabBarController (here called controller) to get access to the navigation bar and tableview controller using the UITabBarController `moreNavigationController` property.

```
#define BACKGROUNDCOLOUR [UIColor colorWithRed:253.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:240.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{    
    //... other init code

    UINavigationBar *moreNavBar = controller.moreNavigationController.navigationBar;

    moreNavBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    UITableView *moreTableView = (UITableView *)controller.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view;

    [moreTableView initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    [moreTableView setBackgroundColor:BACKGROUNDCOLOUR];

    [self.window addSubview:controller.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```